# How to get ChatGPT API working with backend to frontend when getting CORS Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to get a final project working with the ChatGPT API working. Just running my the ChatGPT API in Node.js works great, but I need to interact with the front end to get user input where I ask the user what mood they're in and also ask why they feel the way they do, and relay that to the back end so that the ChatGPT API can respond. I keep getting this error:

> "mood-mental-health-git-testconnectapi-savannahcode.vercel.app/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api/completions' from origin 'https://mood-mental-health-git-testconnectapi-savannahcode.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
> localhost:3000/api/completions:1
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

This is what my code looks like:

**server.js:**

```
import express from "express"
import "dotenv/config.js"
import cors from "cors"
const cors = require("cors")
import OpenAI from "openai"

const openai = new OpenAI(process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY)

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://localhost:3000", // Allow all origins
  methods: ["GET", "POST"], // Allow GET and POST requests
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"], // Allow Content-Type and Authorization headers
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  )
  next()
})

app.post("/api/completions", async (req, res) => {
  const userMood = req.body.userMood
  const userMoodReason = req.body.userMoodReason

  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    messages: [
      {
        role: "system",
        content: `User is feeling ${userMood}. The reason they're feeling this way is ${userMoodReason}. They struggle with their mental health at varying times to varying degrees. Please advise the user with good advice.`,
      },
    ],
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  })

  res.json(completion.choices[0].message.content)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server listening on port 3000"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, world!")
})
```

**index.js:**

```
let userMood = ``
    let userMoodReason = ``
    let userMoodAdvice = ``
.....
    submitBtnHolder.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      if (event.target.classList.contains("submitBtn2")) {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/completions", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            userMood: userMood,
            userMoodReason: userMoodReason,
          }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log("Success:", data)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error:", error)
          })

        userMoodReason = document.querySelector(".textarea").value
        console.log(userMoodReason)
        submitBtnHolder.innerHTML = ``
        moodBtnGroup.innerHTML = ``
        questionAsker.innerHTML = `Your Caring AI Recommendation:`
        hiddenAdvice.style.display = "block"
        hiddenAdvice.firstChild.innerText = `${userMoodAdvice}`
      }
    })`
```

I've installed CORS and tried all sorts of variations to get it work, including a serverless function, installing vercel's CLI, and more. I've included importing cors. I also read over these resources: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation. I'm expecting the response to be console logged

Comment: Note the difference: `origin: "https://localhost:3000", // Allow all origin` `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/completions", {` - CORS works on origins which includes the PROTOCOL

Comment: Ironically, if the cors config DID allow ALL (as per comment) .... also `app.use(cors(corsOptions)); const app = express()` in that order - I take it your server isn't running AT ALL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+enable+CORS+is%3Aquestion&mixed=1

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not convinced it's required - I'm sure I've seen preflight responses without it being included, and since access-control-allow-methods is only a preflight response, it'd be odd if OPTIONS was not allowed :p